# permisos para classroom

Tags: google-apps-script, permisos

Tengo esta línea en un app script de una hoja de Google:

```
Classroom.Courses.Students.create({ 'userId': idEstudiante }, idClase);
```

Su propósito es dar de alta a un alumno en una clase de `Classroom`. Mi cuenta es de `WORKSPACE`, además agregué el servicio de Classroom y soy el propietario de las clases que he creado. No obstante, al ejecutar el script, obtengo este error:

> API call to classroom.courses.students.create failed with error: The caller does not have permission

Si alguien pudiese ayudarme con ello, se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Bienvenido. Necesitas mostrar más información. ¿En qué lenguaje?

Comment: Es la API de Google Classroom , regularmente se usa PHP o Google App Script @Mateo

Comment: @Mateo por lo que dice la etiqueta de apps script que acabo de agregar se usa una versión modificada de Javascript

Comment: Muchas Gracias por sus respuestas, el problema lo pude solucionar de la siguiente manera, por si le sirve a alguien:

El caso es que en Workspace para estudiantes,por políticas de Google un maestro no puede crear usuarios pero si puede añadirlos a un curso de Classroom con la siguiente líne en lugar de

Classroom.Courses.Students.create
utilizando:

Classroom.Invitations.create
 y con eso invita al curso a los alumnos (enviando la invitación por email); que tengamos en una lista en la hoja.

Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

El problema como se indica en el mensaje de error son los permisos:

> API call to classroom.courses.students.create failed with error: The
> caller does not have permission

es importante asegurar [definir el scope](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes): https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses

en tu archivo `appsscript.json` dentro de  "`oauthScopes`".

```
"oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses",
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
  ]
```

Comment: tengo este archivo appsscript.json :
{
  "timeZone": "America/Mexico_City",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Classroom",
        "version": "v1",
        "serviceId": "classroom"
      },
      {
        "userSymbol": "Sheets",
        "version": "v4",
        "serviceId": "sheets"
      },
      {
        "userSymbol": "Drive",
        "version": "v2",
        "serviceId": "drive"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}

Comment: falta que agreges el array donde se definen los scopes que es "oauthScopes".

Comment: LO TENGO ASÍ:   "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses"
   ]

Comment: Y continúa el mismo error!

Answer (score 0):

Muchas Gracias por sus respuestas, el problema lo pude solucionar de la siguiente manera, por si le sirve a alguien:

El caso es que en Workspace para estudiantes,por políticas de Google un maestro no puede crear usuarios pero si puede añadirlos a un curso de Classroom con la siguiente líne en lugar de

Classroom.Courses.Students.create
utilizando:

Classroom.Invitations.create
y con eso invita al curso a los alumnos (enviando la invitación por email); que tengamos en una lista en la hoja.

Gracias!!!